# What should be $k$ so the probability will be $\frac23$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

There is n toys in a box and $\frac{n}2$ kids. Each kid choose $\epsilon$$n$ toys randomly from the box (and independently to the other kids choices ($0<\epsilon<1$)).
We choose k toys randomly from the box.
We define P as the probability that the k toys contain at least 1 toy from each kid $\epsilon$$n$ chosen toys.
What should be the minimal k so that P > $\frac23$?

My try: **[Edited]**
The probability that the k toys don't contains any toys from 1 kid $\epsilon$$n$ chosen toys is **bounded by** $(1-\epsilon)^k$ 
I also know that $(1-\epsilon)^k <$ $e^{-k\epsilon}$
So P > $(1-e^{-k\epsilon})^{\frac{n}2}$.
Here I get stuck because I  having hard time finding k so that P>$\frac23$.

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: Not following your calculation.  First of all, the probability that your selection fails to represent one particular kid is not what you say it is.  It is $\binom {n-\epsilon n}k/\binom nk$.  Secondly, and (I think) more seriously you can't easily use that to compute the probability that no kids are unrepresented.  You need to consider the possibility that two or more kids are unrepresented and use Inclusion-Exclusion or something along those lines.

Comment: you are right about the probability, I forget to mention it is a bound and not the exact probability. I've tried Inclusion-Exclusion but couldn't get an appropriate expression for $k$.